# UIImage vs NSImage: Drawing to an off screen image in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsimage

In mac osx (cocoa), It is very easy to make a blank image of a specific size and draw to it off screen:

```
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(64,64)];
[image lockFocus];
/* drawing code here */
[image unlockFocus];
```

However, in iOS (cocoa touch) there does not seem to be equivalent calls for UIImage. I want to use UIImage (or some other equivalent class) to do the same thing. That is, I want to make an explicitly size, initially empty image to which I can draw using calls like `UIRectFill(...)` and `[UIBezierPath stroke]`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CoreGraphics is needed here, as UIImage does not have high level functions like what you explained..

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(64,64));

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// drawing code here (using context)

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(64, 64));
//Drawing code here
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here is Apple's [Graphics and Drawing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) reference.

Comment: But don't forget to end the image context!

Comment: Ok I assume that this is equivalent to creating the `NSImage` and calling `lockFocus`, but how would I unlock focus?

Comment: Using the function `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mySize, NO, 0.0f);       
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

[myImage drawInRect:myImageRect];
[myText drawAtPoint:myOrigin withFont:myFont];

UIGraphicsPopContext();
UIImage *myNewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Notice you'll want to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions rather than UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, so that you draw in the scale supported by the device. Using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext will look poor on a retina display.

Comment: `UIGraphicsPushContext(context);` and `UIGraphicsPopContext();` can be removed because `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mySize, NO, 0.0f);` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();` already do that.