# Custom Calendar view as table header Causing lag in the table

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have a custom Calendar view which i use to set as the table header of my table view.

Suppose i have 20 rows in the table & i scroll to bottom of the table it works fine but when i scroll back to top & table header is visible to me then the application lags.

I have added custom buttons showing dates to a view & that view is added as table header(Custom Calendar). I have a doubt that whether table header is rendered every time it comes back into screen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your Calendar is indeed re-rendered each time.

You could display your Calendar into an off-screen image, copy that image into a UIImage, then use that UIImage as your table header.

On Classic Mac OS, one would use a GWorld for that.  How about iOS... one cannot do it directly with UIImage, one must use a few CoreGraphics calls as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829475/uiimage-vs-nsimage-drawing-to-an-off-screen-image-in-ios).

Comment: Actually I need to create a calendar like that of iOS where user will tap on a particular date and i will show events on that date in the tableViewCells. Therefore UIImage won't work for me. 
So far what i have debugged i have found that it is because of the buttons(dates) of the calendar which are making the header heavy. Can there be an option that table header is not re-rendered each time?